# Display different error messages if input is empty/incorrect after user touches

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have this same code for two other login/signup components and it works fine, but in this specific component nothing works. No red box pops up under the field saying "email is required" or "password requires" if the user touches the input field and then leaves without typing anything or inputting incorrect information. Is there something wrong here?

Also is my email regex/logic right? My other login page displays "valid email address required" even if the email currently in the input field is something like "test1@gmail.com"

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form centerForm">
    <h1>Child Sign Up</h1>
    <form [formGroup]="signUp" (ngSubmit)="onSignUp(signUp)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Parent ID: </label>
        <input placeholder="ID" formControlName="parentID" required />
        <div
          *ngIf="parentID.invalid && (signUp.submitted || parentID.touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger"
        >
          <div *ngIf="parentID.errors.required">Parent ID is required.</div>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input
          placeholder="email"
          formControlName="email"
          required
          pattern="/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/"
        />
        <div
          *ngIf="email.invalid && (signUp.submitted || email.touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger"
        >
          <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email address is required.</div>
          <div *ngIf="email.errors.pattern">
            Please enter a valid email address.
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input
          placeholder="first and last name"
          formControlName="name"
          required
        />
        <div
          *ngIf="name.invalid && (signUp.submitted || name.touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger"
        >
          <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">Name is required.</div>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          formControlName="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          ng-minlength="8"
          required
          pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"
        />
        <div
          *ngIf="password.invalid && (signUp.submitted || password.touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger"
        >
          <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">Password is required.</div>
          <div *ngIf="password.errors.pattern">
            Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase
            letter, and at least 8 or more characters.
          </div>
        </div>

        <br />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm Password: </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          formControlName="confirmation"
          name="confirmPassword"
          placeholder="confirm password"
          required
          pattern="{{ password.value }}"
        />
        <div
          *ngIf="
            confirmation.invalid && (signUp.submitted || confirmation.touched)
          "
          class="alert alert-danger"
        >
          <div *ngIf="confirmation.errors.required">
            Confirm password is required.
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="confirmation.errors.pattern">Passwords do not match.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component initialize your formGroup as follows,

```
this.signUp = this.formBuilder.group({
    email: ['', Validators.required],
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    password : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
    confirmation: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
});
```

In your template use Validation instead of pattern. Also instead of using the formControl `signUp.get('email')` everytime to get the email, you may use a simple getter,

```
get email() {
    return this.signUp.get('email');
}
```

Then you can replace `signUp.controls['email']` with `email` everywhere in your template.

```
<label>Email</label>
<input placeholder="email"
               formControlName="email"
               required type="text" class="form-control" />
<div *ngIf="(email.dirty || email.touched) && email.invalid && email.errors.required">Email address is required.</div>
<div *ngIf="(email.dirty || email.touched) && email.invalid && email.errors.email">Please enter a valid email address.</div>
```